# KnockoutJS splitting timestamp into month dropdown and year textinput

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

How do I manage to work on a timestamp that initially is null?
I need to set month and year in to steps.
Month in a dropdown and year in a text input field.

fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/DrHyper/azf74/

JS:

```
function AgreementData(data) {
var self = this;
data = data || {};


self.effectiveDate = ko.observable(data.effectiveDate || "");
self.effectiveDateMonth = ko.computed({
    read: function () {
        var dateR = new Date(self.effectiveDate());
        return dateR.getMonth();
    },
    write: function (value) {
        var dateW = new Date(self.effectiveDate());
        dateW.setMonth(value);
        self.effectiveDate(dateW.getTime());
    },
    owner: self
});
self.effectiveDateYear = ko.computed({
    read: function () {
        var dateR = new Date(self.effectiveDate());
        return dateR.getFullYear() ? dateR.getFullYear() : "";
    },
    write: function (value) {
        var dateW = new Date(self.effectiveDate());
        dateW.setFullYear(value);
        self.effectiveDate(dateW.getTime());
    }
});
}

var Month = function (monthIndex, monthString) {
this.monthIndex = monthIndex;
this.monthString = monthString;
};

function AgreementViewModel() {
var self = this;
self.agreement = ko.observable(new AgreementData());
self.months = ko.observableArray([new Month(0, 'Januar'), new Month(1, 'Februar'), 
new Month(2, 'Marts'), new Month(3, 'April'), new Month(4, 'Maj'), 
new Month(5, 'Juni'), new Month(6, 'Juli'), new Month(7, 'August'), 
new Month(8, 'September'), new Month(9, 'Oktober'), new Month(10, 'November'), 
new Month(11, 'December')]);

//    self.postAgreement = function () {
//        var jsonData = ko.toJSON(self.agreement);
//        $.post("/sam-rest/agreements", jsonData, function(returnedData) {
//            // This callback is executed if the post was successful
//        })
//
//    };
//
//    self.getAgreement = function (agreementNumber) {
//        $.getJSON("/sam-rest/agreements/"+agreementNumber, function (jsonData) {
//            self.agreement(new AgreementData(jsonData));
//        });
//
//    };
//
//    Sammy(function() {
//            this.get('#:action/:agreementNmb', function() {
//                self.action(this.params.action);
//                self.getAgreement(this.params.agreementNmb);
//            });
//    }).run();

}

var agreementViewModel = new AgreementViewModel();
ko.applyBindings(agreementViewModel);
```

HTML:

```
<form>
Month: <select id="effectiveDateMonth" data-bind="options: months,
                     optionsText: 'monthString',
                     optionsValue: 'monthIndex',
                     value: agreement().effectiveDateMonth,
                     optionsCaption: 'Choose...'"></select>
Year: <input type="text" data-bind="value: agreement().effectiveDateYear" placeholder="YYYY" />
<hr>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create something like observableDate that share month and year as observable:

```
ko.observableDate = function (value) {
    var month = ko.observable(null);
    var year = ko.observable(null);
    var date = ko.computed({
        read: function() {
            if (year() !== null && month() !== null) {
                return new Date(year(), month(), 1);
            }
            else {
                return null;
            }
        },
        write: function (date) {
            if (date) {
                month(date.getMonth());
                year(date.getYear());
            }
            else {
                month(null); 
                year(null);
            }
        }
    });
    date(value);
    date.year = year;
    date.month = month;

    return date;
};
```

and then bind to `year` and `month`:

```
<form>
Month: <select id="effectiveDate.month" data-bind="options: months,
                     optionsText: 'monthString',
                     optionsValue: 'monthIndex',
                     value: agreement().effectiveDate.month,
                     optionsCaption: 'Choose...'"></select>
Year: <input type="text" data-bind="value: agreement().effectiveDate.year" placeholder="YYYY" />
<hr>
</form>
```

Full sample: http://jsfiddle.net/UXjBf/7/

Comment: Works fine! With only a slight modification: use date.getFullYear() instead of: date.getYear()